# How can I delete my account

Tags: support

I want to delete my account in `Photos.SE`

How can I do this and is the deletion permanent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have never posted never voted or posted a question or answer more than once, you should see a self-delete option on your user page next to the edit link

[image: Self-Delete]

However, if your account has voted or posted, do the following:

> 1. Edit the "About Me" section of your profile to say ***"please delete me"***.
> 2. Fill out and submit [**this form**](https://photo.stackexchange.com/help/user-deletion)

Moderators will then look into your account and delete it. You will be notified of deletion via email. Make sure you use the correct email address and the user link. (By default, these fields are already filled)

Please note that **user deletion is irreversible!**